# Graphical interface to git with support for signed commits?

Tags: git, gui, gnupg

Is there any graphical interfaces to Git with support for gpg signed commits?

I've tried the "Tools" -> "Add..." way of the builtin git gui that comes with git but that doesnt work with `commit -S`.

Would love if it works on Windows XP and Linux.

Comment: Apparently, it will be added to SourceTree soon https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1174

Comment: Thanks, yeah. Saw this as well but not sure if this is just for Mac. And I would also like if the app is supported by Windows XP